# StlSoft - how to use their file system functionality?

Tags: c++, stl, filesystems

I'm trying to add portability to the file system in an application I wrote. To this end, I'm using [stlsoft](http://www.stlsoft.org), but I can't figure out how to use anything. Is there a tutorial somewhere, or a relevant example? They have samples on the site, but as far as I can see none relating to the filesystem module.

Comment: Switch to Boost.Filesystem instead, it's being maintained and it's well-documented.

Comment: It's not entirely my decision... But if I can't find decent documentation that's what I'll do, yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...Eh, looks like I'll be using Boost instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Boost.Filesystem is good, but heavy (boost.filesystem + boost.system).

Here the simple "ls" utility as example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include <platformstl/platformstl.hpp>
#include <platformstl/filesystem/readdir_sequence.hpp>

using platformstl::readdir_sequence;   

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    readdir_sequence entries(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : ".", 
            readdir_sequence::files|readdir_sequence::directories);
    std::copy(entries.begin(), entries.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<char const*>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Also you can check recls (Recursive LS) project on Sourceforge for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are looking for but [here](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/group__group____library____filesystem.html) is the documentation to the stlsoft filesystem module.