# File system iterator for C++

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator, directory-listing

I'd like a basic C++ STL-like container for the filesystem.

e.g.

```
std::filesystem::const_iterator i = filesys.begin();  
i->file_name(); i->full_path(),
```

etc..

Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It exists. Almost similar, atleast which can work with the STL iterators and containers.

[boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html)

Example:

```
path p ("directorypath");
std::vector<path> v;                      
std::copy(directory_iterator(p), directory_iterator(), std::back_inserter(v));
for (std::vector<path>::const_iterator it=v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
{
     std::cout << "   " << *it << std::endl;
}
```

I suppose, now you would like to  look at `directory_iterator` to discover what else it provides.

Comment: And it's going in TR2, so it will be shipping as part of the standard library in the not-too-distant future.

Answer (score 2):

Another one is [STLSOFT](http://www.stlsoft.org/) platformstl::readdir_sequence.

Example provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794755/stlsoft-how-to-use-their-file-system-functionality)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) library has this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ 2012 has something now. See [C++11 filesystem (VS2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12151351/c11-filesystem-vs2012). Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694.aspx for the VS2013 implementation.