# C++11 filesystem (VS2012)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-c++-2012, c++-tr2

I am having a lot of trouble finding any documentation on the  header included with vs2012. I see that it is mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) but they don't provide a link on how to use it. What I am really looking for is documentation for how to use it, with the visual studio implementation being preferred. Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `<filesystem>` header is not part of C++11; it is a proposal for C++ TR2 based on the [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/) library.  Visual C++ 2012 includes an implementation of the proposed library.

See [the MSDN documentation for the `<filesystem>` header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694) and [the C++ TR2 proposal on which the implementation is based](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1975.html) (the latest TR2 proposal is [N3335](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3335.html) from January, but I don't know what has changed or whether the Visual C++ 2012 implementation includes any of the most recent changes).

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why this was so hard to search for... I will accept as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: Note that it's based on Boost.FileSystem _v2_, which is no longer included in current Boost distributions (v3 has replaced it altogether). So, if one is going to use the Boost documentation, they'll need to use the [Boost 1.49.0 docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm) at latest.

Comment: I wish VC's compiler team was as dedicated as its library team.  STL is a machine.